# What does a gold band in the third position on a resistor with 5th band being white mean?

Tags: resistors, code, color

Any idea how I am supposed to interpret this component? I would not have expected a gold in third position for a resistor with 5 colors.

[image]

Edit: this [other thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/406505/identifying-a-resistor-with-a-weird-band-combination) gives explanation as to how to interpret a gold in third position on a 5 band resistor, but points out that the 5th band would then be the temperature coefficient band. However white is not a valid color for temperature coefficient.

Comment: Based on that, 5.6R 5%

Comment: It's an interesting problem because white isn't a standard tempco band but even reading it backwards, gold can't be a second sig fig band.  If it *were* tempco, it would be...1ppm/K?  What piece of equipment did this come out of?

Comment: @vir it may not be a tempco band but something else. There's a bunch of other options, often vendor-specific.

Comment: Maybe a fusible resistor. Looks like a MOF flameproof type anyway. Do not substitute an ordinary film type.

Comment: @vir, this came out of a circuit in a toaster.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany is correct: this is almost certainly a fusible resistor:

https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/447/Yageo_LR_FKN_1-1947941.pdf
Page 1: "5th color code: white"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is perfectly normal. Gold multiplier is 0.1.

Your resistor is 56 x 0.1 or 5.6 ohms, 5% tolerance.

The extra white band means it's somehow special.

But we cannot know what it means, only make good guess.

It depends on what the resistor does in the circuit that requires it to be special in some way and why a standard resistor will not work properly in place of this resistor.

A likely guess, but only a guess, is that the extra white ring may mean it is a fusible resistor, designed to blow safely instead of burning up.

Do not replace with a standard resistor for safety reasons, you may end up with a device which is ready to start fires when the special feature of the resistor is needed the next time.

It may also mean a lot of other things like being non-inductive.